# Angular 8 deep nested routing, named outlet and lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular8

I'm developing an app that have 4 router outlets (main one and 3 names outlets). I am using lazy loading to have good performance but I can't get my routing working on the last level of nesting. Either the path is known but the component is not displayed in the named outlet, either Angular throws Cannot match any route etc.

Here is my `app-routing.module.ts` :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'onboarding', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'onboarding',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/onboarding/onboarding.module').then(
        m => m.OnboardingPageModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    canActivate [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserPageModule) 

  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
      paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Then in my `user-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'conversations'
      },
      {
        path: 'conversations',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@pages/user-conversations/user-conversations.module').then(
            m => m.UserConversationsPageModule
          )
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@pages/settings/settings.module').then(
            m => m.SettingsPageModule
          )
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Here settings works fine. I want to go deeper in the path of conversations, `user-conversations-routing.module.ts` looks like :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserConversationsPage,
    outlet: 'user',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':conversationId',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('@pages/conversation/conversation.module').then(m => m.ConversationPageModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And finally `conversation-routing-module.ts` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConversationPage,
    outlet: 'conversations',
  }
];
```

With this config, I'm not able to get the last nested level to work, when I type : `user/conversations/-LxDT9dq5RIhcFi0VpcO`, I get Cannot match any routes error from Angular and nothing is displayed in the last outlet.

I've tried lots of things but can't get it work. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I'm using the `conversationId` ? Any help would be appreciated :) 
If that can make any difference, I'm using Ionic 4.